# Using puppeteer page.evaluate to return a value that I can use outside of the browser context

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, cumulative-layout-shift

I am using page.evaluate to record each CLS entry on the browser and I am trying to save it to a variable that I can use outside the browser context. I am doing this as follows:

```
page.exposeFunction('getCLSEntries', list => {
  //console.log("list:", list);
  let clsList = JSON.parse(list);
  return clsList;
});
console.log("CLS List:", clsList);

let cls = new Map();
while (scrollCount < maxScrolls) {
    //console.log("Function exposed"
    
    cls[scrollCount] = await page.evaluate(() => {
        console.log("reportCLSInstances called");
        let clsEntries = [];
        let clsInstances = [];
        const internalCLSInstances = (list) => {
            clsEntries = list.getEntries();
            const entries = JSON.stringify(clsEntries);
            window.getCLSEntries(entries).then((value) => {
                clsInstances.push(value);
                console.log("value: ", value);
            });
            console.log("CLS Instances 1:", clsInstances);
        };
        const observer = new PerformanceObserver(internalCLSInstances);
        observer.observe({type: 'layout-shift', buffered: true});
        console.log("CLS Instances 2:", clsInstances);
        return clsInstances;
    });
    console.log("CLS: ", cls);
```

However, each return of page.evaluate gives me [], even when the array is populated in the log statement just before the return. What am I doing wrong?

When I replace the return value of page.evaluate to ["hello"], it populates my map as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two levels of asynchronous code between the empty `clsInstances` that's currently returned and the version that's eventually populated but never seen:

- the callback passed into `PerformanceObserver` is called in some turn of the event loop after the function passed to `page.evaluate()` has returned the initial empty array
- the call to `getCLSEntries` is asynchronous (returning a promise), making the synchronous `internalCLSInstances` callback also not actually complete by the time it returns.

The answer to this is typically to wrap the whole thing in a Promise and `resolve` it where the work is actually complete.

There's a lot of lines in here that I'm assuming were added while debugging (like I'm not sure of the reason for passing back to node code in `getCLSEntries` except maybe for logging?), but assuming everything is necessary:

```js
    cls[scrollCount] = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("reportCLSInstances called");
        let clsEntries = [];
        let clsInstances = [];
        const internalCLSInstances = (list) => {
            clsEntries = list.getEntries();
            const entries = JSON.stringify(clsEntries);
            window.getCLSEntries(entries).then((value) => {
                clsInstances.push(...value);
                console.log("value: ", value);
                resolve(clsInstances);
            });
            console.log("CLS Instances 1:", clsInstances);
        };
        const observer = new PerformanceObserver(internalCLSInstances);
        observer.observe({type: 'layout-shift', buffered: true});
        console.log("CLS Instances 2:", clsInstances);
      });
    });
```

(This snippet also spreads the `value` array, assuming the goal is an array of `layout-shift` entries, not an array where the first element is an array of `layout-shift` entries)